# Prove Polynomial is Reducible in Field of Prime Characteristic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let F be a field of characteristic h, where h is prime. Prove that $x^h+1$ is reducible in F[x].

Is the following sufficient?

The Freshman's Dream is applicable in fields of prime characteristic. Thus, $(x+1)^h=(x^h+1^h)=(x^h+1)$. This implies every polynomial of the form $(x^h+1)$ is reducible by $(x+1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you've shown that you can express $x^h - 1$ as a product of two nonconstant polynomials (namely, $x - 1$ and $(x - 1)^{h-1}$). If this is for an assignment, you might want to make sure you're allowed to assume the freshman's dream statement, as one might consider that the result trivializes the problem.

More generally, if $h > 1$, $x^h - 1$ is always reducible in any characteristic; by the formula for geometric series, we have
$$
\frac{x^h - 1}{x - 1} = 1 + x + \dots + x^{h-1},
$$
so that
$$
x^h - 1 = (x - 1)(1 + x + \dots + x^{h-1})
$$
is a factorization into two nonconstant polynomials.

**After the edit:** Yes, that argument shows that $(x + 1)(x + 1)^{h-1}$ is a decomposition of $x^h + 1$ into two nonconstant polynomials. Just make sure you can justify using the freshman's dream statement, and that you state it properly: $(x + y)^p = x^p + y^p$ if $x,y\in A$, where $A$ is a ring of characteristic $p$ (which $F[x]$ is, if $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$).